# Linux bash parse json: Get first & last date

Tags: json, regex, linux, bash

I have a JSON variable from curl like the below (@stackoverflow=pretty printed) and I want to get two pieces of information. The date which is the first calendar date and the last calendar date (ISO 8601), but I have no idea how to do this in bash. On top I have to calculate the duration between these two dates (could be just some milliseconds or much more).

Anyone any idea how I can solve my problem?

```
{
    "results": [{
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2012-09-15T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2015-09-15T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2015-09-11T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2015-09-15T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2015-09-15T14:04:30.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "2019-09-15T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    },
    {
        "...": "...",
        "date": "1015-09-15T14:04:00.741+0200",
        "...": "..."
    }]
}
```

**For your information:** Its a test script I have to use, because there is some more magic in it I don't want to rewrite in other script languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

```
   echo $JSON | tr '"' '\n' | sed -n '/date/{n;n;p}'
   dates=$(echo $JSON | tr '"' '\n' | sed -n '/date/{n;n;p}')
   for date in ${dates[@]}
      do
      echo $date
   done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the JSON and extract all the dates, then sort them and output the first and last dates.

```
curl ... | jq '.results[] | .date' | sort | awk 'NR==1; END {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what the setting is, but if you have text in a variable names JSON, you can extract the lines containing the desired dates with:

```
echo "$JSON" | awk '/date/ && !a++; /date/ {l=$0} END {print l}'
```

(Depending on the deleted content; you might get some false hits and need a more tightly constrained regex).  But parsing json with shell tools is really a bad idea.